# Fibonacci series in python 3 displays only final number

Tags: python, recursion, fibonacci

I'm a beginner for Python and trying to print Fibonacci series recursively. When i try this, the return function doesn't print at all, hence just the argument that i pass gets printed.

Here's the code:

```
def fibR(n):
 if n == 1 or n ==2:
    return (1)
 return(fibR(n-1) + fibR(n-2))
print(fibR(5))
```

Can someone help me to get all the numbers in the series?

Comment: You don't need all those extra parentheses in the `return` statement.

Comment: If you want the function to print results you'll have to add a `print` within the function to show the values you want, otherwise only the final result will be printed

Comment: Adding on to @EricRenouf's suggestion, you could put together a list of the results and return the list.

Comment: Including two recursive calls is the naïve solution, by the way. Look around and you'll find some faster recursive methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inefficient way to do this is to use a loop:

```
def fibR(n):
    if n == 1 or n ==2:
        return 1
    return fibR(n-1) + fibR(n-2)

for i in range(1,6):
    print(fibR(i))
```

However, this is inefficient because it will calculate the lower Fibonacci numbers more than once. You can use an array to store the intermediate Fibonacci numbers and improve performance:

```
def fibR(n):
    if n > len(fibR.values) - 1:
        for i in range(len(fibR.values), n+1):
            fibR.values.append(fibR(i-2) + fibR(i-1))
    return fibR.values[n]

fibR.values = [0, 1, 1]
for i in range(1,6):
    print(fibR(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic (but not naïve) recursive Fibonacci solution is as follows:

```
>>> def fib(num, first=0, second=1):
...     if not num: return second
...     return fib(num-1, second, first+second)
...
>>> fib(5)
8
```

You can save the intermediate values in two ways: create a `list` and `append()` to it, or have your function `return` a `tuple`.

Method 1:

```
>>> def fibl(num, first=0, second=1):
...     results.append(second)
...     if not num: return
...     return fibl(num-1, second, first+second)
...
>>> results = []
>>> fibl(5)
>>> results
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
```

Method 2:

```
>>> def fibr(num, first=0, second=1, *results):
...     if not num: return results+(second,)
...     return fibr(num-1, second, first+second, *(results + (second,)))
...
>>> fibr(5)
(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8)
```